# Django Alluth Authentication Error in Production

Tags: python, reactjs, django, backend, google-signin

I have integrated Google Login on production site.
Basically Backend-Django(port-8000),Frontend-React(port-3000) inegration.

I have manage successfully login with google login on

```
http://example.com:8000/accounts/login/
```

But on Frontend its shows error.

```
http://example.com:3000
```

ERROR is
[image]

Now on my Google OauthId credentials are

**Authorized JavaScript origins**

```
http://example.com:8000

http://example.com:3000
```

**Authorized redirect URIs**

```
http://example.com:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
```

The error is not understanble for me as i am new to django world.
Can someone guide me.

Comment: Did you add your production URL to your Google account ?

Comment: yes I have mention,see above i have given the example.com instead of my domain